# Check user credentials in Azure AD using PHP

Tags: php, android, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Our company has a mobile app. Until now we used LDAP authentication using PHP code to login on the app using the company's Active Directory user and password.

Now they tell me we have to stop using LDAP because there has been some security breach.

My question is, is there an equivalent of `ldap_bind` for Azure AD?
I've been looking for information and the answers I found are too complicated and elaborated.

Would be better to use a Native Azure App to link to our mobile App or is the PHP aproach better?

I don't need to get the Azure AD token and be able to do some operations or anything. I just want to check if user & password are correct and that's it.

Any guidance would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to redirect the user to authenticate e.g. by using the OpenId Connect protocol.
LDAP is not supported in AAD.

The user may have e.g. Multi-Factor Authentication enabled and thus there is no way to surely authenticate programmatically.

So the right way is to register a Native app, and authenticate from your mobile app using ADAL or MSAL.

Comment: You have been very helful, thank you. I have a follow up question: When I write my email and password on the prompt window, as soon as I click on login the app closes. No errors or warnings. When I open it again I get the success messages. Any idea why?

Comment: That's... weird. You can open a new question with the relevant code and the behavior you see.